# How can I expire all my sessions in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, fitnesse

I would like to expire all my sessions in Tomcat. We test our product under Fitnesse and some sessions remain and the end of the session causes dependency between the tests. I do it by hand with the following code, but some sessions remain (I can check it with the http://localhost:8080/manager/html/list url)

```
public static void expireAllSessions() {
    String[] applications = { "a", "b", "c", "d",  "e" };
    for (String application : applications) {
        try {
            expireAllSessions(application);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
}

private static void expireAllSessions(final String application) throws Exception {
    // cf doc http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
    Credentials userPassword = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("tomcat", "tomcat");
    client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, userPassword);

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/manager/html/expire";
    NameValuePair[] parametres = new NameValuePair[] {
            new NameValuePair("path", "/" + application),
            new NameValuePair("idle", "0")
    };
    HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
    method.setQueryString(parametres);
    client.executeMethod(method);
}
```

Is there a way to do it more efficiently and immediate with no remaining session ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming your applications are really independent contexts.  I have done something similar to what you are asking using an `HttpSessionListener` for every context.  The tricky part here is that you need to have a Session Collection that is loaded by the root class loader as opposed to the context class loader.  This is how I remember it:

Create a class which holds the active sessions for each context.  This class **must** reside in the tomcat /lib directory so that it becomes accessible by every context.  It can't be part of any of the contexts.

```
public class SessionMap {

  private static Map<ServletContext, Set<HttpSession>> map =
    new HashMap<ServletContext, Set<HttpSession>>();

  private SessionMap() {
  }

  public static Map<ServletContext, Set<HttpSession>> getInstance() {
    return map;
  }

  public static void invalidate(String[] contexts) {
    synchronized (map) {
      List<String> l = Arrays.asList(contexts);     
      for (Map.Entry<ServletContext, Set<HttpSession>> e : map.entrySet()) {
        // context name without the leading slash
        String c = e.getKey().getContextPath().substring(1);
        if (l.contains(c)) {
          for (HttpSession s : e.getValue()) 
            s.invalidate();
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Create a listener for every context.

```
public class ApplicationContextListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    ConcurrentMap<ServletContext, Set<HttpSession>> instance = SessionMap.getInstance();
    synchronized (instance) {
      ServletContext c = event.getSession().getServletContext();
      Set<HttpSession> set = instance.get(c);
      if (c == null) {
        set = new HashSet<HttpSession>();
        instance.put(c, set);
      }
      set.add(event.getSession());
    }
  }

  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    ConcurrentMap<ServletContext, Set<HttpSession>> instance = SessionMap.getInstance();
    synchronized (map) {
      ServletContext c = event.getSession().getServletContext();
      Set<HttpSession> set = instance.get(c);
      if (c != null) {
        set.remove(event.getSession());
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Registered each listener in the corresponding context's `web.xml`.

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>ApplicationContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You can then call the following line to invalidate everything from any context.

```
SessionMap.invalidate();
```

I'm synchronizing on the map just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 3):

You could use HttpSessionListener to save the references to sessions in a data structure and then use it at your leisure

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Lamda Probe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/index.htm)? For each of your web applications, you can view the contents of the session and expire them (all).

[image]

If you are keen on writing your own app to do this instead; Lamda Probe is open source, so you could take code from them to help accomplish your goal.

Comment: Looks like Lambda Probe is abandonware but there's an active fork of it called [Psi Probe](https://psi-probe.github.io/psi-probe/).