# BlazeDS Maintenance Window: Invalidate All Active Sessions

Tags: session, blazeds, invalidation

How to invalidate all active sessions in BlazeDS during maintenance window?

When the system administrator wants to perform maintenance
tasks, we will display a warning message to all the users of the
flex application that the system will be offline after 30 minutes. Once the
countdown is finished, we would like to close all the sessions that
are active. If users perform any request to the system, it will be kicked off and redirect to a maintenance page. We are not planning to shutdown the system.

How to achieve above without manually keep track of all active sessions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in BlazeDS which can help you to invalidate all the sessions..so you will have to rely on your tracking code. Or maybe you can find a specific solution for your application server (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744021/is-it-a-possible-to-invalidate-an-individual-session-in-jboss-through-jmx) link)

Comment: Here is how tracking code looks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960711/how-can-i-expire-all-my-sessions-in-tomcat/3964797#3964797