# request.getSession(false).invalidate not work after logout

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a webproject with tomcat, java, jsp, servlets. 
If i logout on my webproject frontend, i want to destroy all sessions. But the following code doesn' work. I expect that all session are destroyed and that if i logout, i have to authentificate in next step with my user and passwort as normal. Thank you for your help.

```
if(lstrAction!=null && lstrAction.equals(ApplicationConstants.LOGOUT)){

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if(session != null){
                session.invalidate();
                session = request.getSession(false);
            }

        }
```

I have debug my project, and i found tha the session is not null after the last line.

Comment: Does the session also still contain all variables which was stored in it?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960711/how-can-i-expire-all-my-sessions-in-tomcat

Comment: `session.getId()`? The essential thing, is that in the next request there is no session.

Comment: as @w4rumy said , is there also paramaeters values in the session , because when you intantiate the session object by lat line it may create an empty session

Comment: I guess `session = request.getSession(false);` gives you a session, but an invalid one.

Comment: Why are you calling `session.get(false)` twice? Remove the second call and set your `session` variable to `null`.

Comment: @EJP: Why to set the Session explicitly null. After calling session.invalidate() the session object with key session.getIdInternal(), is removed from the Map of sessions according to tomcat implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
session.invalidate();
session = request.getSession(false);
```

Here after invalidate of session you are reassign the session. In this point it will not be null. You need to do a null checking to find session is null or not.

Answer (score -1):

try this code. It surely works for you.

Cookie c[]=request.getCookies();  if(c==null){  response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); }  else  {         session.removeAttribute(c[0].getValue());  response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");  }